# tensorflow data validation tfdv fails on google cloud dataflow with "Can't get attribute 'NumExamplesStatsGenerator' "

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, tensorflow-data-validation

I am following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/data_validation/get_started#running_on_google_cloud) "get started" tensorflow tutorial on how to run tfdv on apache beam on google cloud dataflow. My code is very similar to the one in the tutorial:

```
import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions, StandardOptions, SetupOptions, WorkerOptions

PROJECT_ID = 'my-project-id'
JOB_NAME = 'my-job-name'
REGION = "europe-west3"
NETWORK = "regions/europe-west3/subnetworks/mysubnet"
GCS_STAGING_LOCATION = 'gs://my-bucket/staging'
GCS_TMP_LOCATION = 'gs://my-bucket/tmp'
GCS_DATA_LOCATION = 'gs://another-bucket/my-data.CSV'
# GCS_STATS_OUTPUT_PATH is the file path to which to output the data statistics
# result.
GCS_STATS_OUTPUT_PATH = 'gs://my-bucket/stats'

# downloaded locally with: pip download tensorflow_data_validation --no-deps --platform manylinux2010_x86_64 --only-binary=:all:
#(would be great to use it have it on cloud storage) PATH_TO_WHL_FILE = 'gs://my-bucket/wheels/tensorflow_data_validation-1.7.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl'
PATH_TO_WHL_FILE = '/Users/myuser/some-folder/tensorflow_data_validation-1.7.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl'


# Create and set your PipelineOptions.
options = PipelineOptions()

# For Cloud execution, set the Cloud Platform project, job_name,
# staging location, temp_location and specify DataflowRunner.
google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
google_cloud_options.project = PROJECT_ID
google_cloud_options.job_name = JOB_NAME
google_cloud_options.staging_location = GCS_STAGING_LOCATION
google_cloud_options.temp_location = GCS_TMP_LOCATION
google_cloud_options.region = REGION
options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'

setup_options = options.view_as(SetupOptions)
# PATH_TO_WHL_FILE should point to the downloaded tfdv wheel file.
setup_options.extra_packages = [PATH_TO_WHL_FILE]

# Worker options
worker_options = options.view_as(WorkerOptions)
worker_options.subnetwork = NETWORK
worker_options.max_num_workers = 2

print("Generating stats...")
tfdv.generate_statistics_from_tfrecord(GCS_DATA_LOCATION, output_path=GCS_STATS_OUTPUT_PATH, pipeline_options=options)
print("Stats generated!")
```

The code above starts a dataflow job but unfortunately it fails with the following error:

```
apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/dill_pickler.py", line 285, in loads
    return dill.loads(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 275, in loads
    return load(file, ignore, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 270, in load
    return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load
    obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 462, in find_class
    return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'NumExamplesStatsGenerator' on <module 'tensorflow_data_validation.statistics.stats_impl' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_data_validation/statistics/stats_impl.py'>
```

I couldn't find on the internet anything similar.
If it can help, on my local machine (MACOS) I have the following versions:

`Apache Beam version: 2.34.0`
`Tensorflow version: 2.6.2`
`TensorFlow Transform version: 1.4.0`
`TFDV version: 1.4.0`

Apache beam on cloud runs with `Apache Beam Python 3.8 SDK 2.34.0`

BONUS QUESTION: Another question I have is around the `PATH_TO_WHL_FILE`. I tried to put it on a storage bucket but Beam doesn't seem to be able to pick it up. Only locally, which is actually a problem, because it would make it more difficult to distribute this code. What would be a good practice to distribute this wheel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the name of the attribute `NumExamplesStatsGenerator`, it's a generator that is not pickle-able.

But I couldn't find the attribute from the [module now](https://github.com/tensorflow/data-validation/blob/master/tensorflow_data_validation/statistics/stats_impl.py).
A search indicates that [in 1.4.0](https://searchcode.com/file/325505618/tensorflow_data_validation/statistics/stats_impl.py/) this module contains this attribute.
So you may want to try a newer versioned TFDV.

PATH_TO_WHL_FILE indicates a file to stage/distribute to Dataflow for execution, so you can use a file on GCS.

Comment: Another thing to doublecheck is to make sure that you have the same version of TFDV on the workers and at job submission (for example that TFDV is not downgraded due to some conflicting requirements when installing additional pipeline dependency packages).

Comment: Upgrading the local TFDV to 1.7.0 did indeed solved the issue. Thanks. Regarding `extra_packages` setup option, is there a way to link a `gs` location rather than a local path for the python package file?

Comment: It looks like it works just by linking a `gs` location rather than a local path. Great.

Comment: Nice! I'll update the answer to reflect your `gs` location investigation.